# Setting 'Run-Protect-Admin-Groups-Task' Extended Right

Tags: active-directory, permissions

I modified the security settings on the [AdminSDHolder object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/appendix-c--protected-accounts-and-groups-in-active-directory) in my domain and takes a very long time to propagate the settings to my admin users. I tried run `runProtectAdminGroupsTask` manually, but `LDP` said I don't have permission to make that change. I see that there is a right (`'Run-Protect-Admin-Groups-Task' (GUID 7726b9d5-a4b4-4288-a6b2-dce952e80a7f)`) required to execute this modify command, but I can't figure out how to set it. I am a member of `Enterprise Admins`, `Schema Admins` and `Domain Admins`.

Command:
[image: LDE modify command]

Error:
[image: LDE with error message]

It looks like `Run Protected Admin Groups Task` is in the permissions list for `Enterprise Admins` already:
[image: <code>Run Protected Admin Groups Task</code>]

Is there another way to set this permission or manually `Run Protected Admin Groups Task`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it appears to have been a problem caused by UAC. Even though `LDP` looks like it is using a regular LDAP bind, there is some non-standard "magic" going on and it needs to be run as administrator too. If I used a different LDAP client, I would have been able to make the change without any trouble.